# How to download LLVM for redhat 32 bits

Tags: linux, llvm, redhat

I want to download LLVM for red hat 32-bit. Have searcher for it on official site of LLVM but can't find it. Can any one help?

Comment: Try a Google search, for instance. It turns up a number of "hits".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step:

Install gcc

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

Install LLVM & Clang

```
sudo yum install clang
```

Check the installed versions, and see their locations.

```
clang --version
    May say: clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)
which clang
    /usr/bin/clang
gcc --version
    May say: gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
g++ --version
    May say: g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
which gcc
    /usr/bin/gcc
which g++
    /usr/bin/g++
```